# How to find Tangent Normal Binornmal vectors of parametric knot

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, frenet-frame

I am given parametric equations of torus knot:

$$x = (a+b\cos(qt))\cos(pt)$$
$$y= (a+b\cos(qt))\sin(pt)$$
$$z= c\sin(qt)$$
where $0<t<2\pi$.

I need to find Tangent, Normal and Binormal vectors. Please explain me so that I can understand.
Thanks!

Comment: you might find this helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its more general. But, I am interested Frenet–Serret formulas especially for knots wrapped around the surface of  torus. Could you guide me with some link or explanation.